# Laravel - foreign key adding an array of data to database and not just id

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys

I have a trips table and a packing table. I created a relationship between the two tables.

Users can create a packing list for their trips, adding items and ticking them off as completed.

The foreign key for the 'Packing' table is the trip_id. 
However when a user adds an item to the packing list getting the error SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value:

It seems like the trip_id field is adding every field from the trips table.
I only want to add the trip id, '17' in this example below...
[image]

**routes**

```
Route::get('/packingList/{id}', 'TaskController@index');
Route::post('/packingList/store', 'TaskController@store')->name('tasks.store');
Route::post('/packingList/update/{id}', 'TaskController@update')->name('tasks.update');
Route::delete('/packingList/{id}', 'TaskController@destroy')->name('tasks.destroy');
```

**packingList.blade.php**

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form method="POST" action="{{route('tasks.store')}}">
      @csrf
      <input value="{{ $trip_id }}" name="trip_id" hidden="true"/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for "title">Title</label>
        <input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="225" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </form>
  </div>
<div class="card-header">Items to Pack</div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      @foreach ($packings as $packing)
      <tr>
        <td>
          @if($packing->is_complete)
            <s> {{$packing->title}} </s>
          @else
            {{$packing->title}}
          @endif
        </td>
        <td class="text-right">
          @if(! $packing->is_complete)
            <form method="POST" action="{{route('tasks.update', $packing->id)}}">
              @csrf
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Complete</button>
            </form>
          @endif
          <form action="{{route('tasks.destroy',[$packing->id])}}" method="POST">
            @method('DELETE')
            @csrf
            <button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
          </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
  </table>

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function index($id) {
    $trip_id = Trip::findOrFail($id);
    $packings = Packing::get();

    return view('packingList')->with('packings', $packings)->with('trip_id', $trip_id);
}

public function store(Request $request) {
  //validate given Request
  $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|string|max:225',
    'trip_id' => 'required'
  ]);

  //create a new incompletete item with given title
  $packings = new Packing;
  $packings->title = $request->input('title');
  $packings->is_complete = false;
  $packings->trip_id = $request['trip_id'];
  $packings->save();

  return redirect('packingList')->with('success', 'Item added to Packing List');
}

public function update(Request $request, $id) {
  //mark task as complete and save it
  $packings = Packing::find($id);
  $packings->is_complete = true;
  $packings->save();

  return redirect('packingList')->with('success', 'Item  Updated');
}

public function destroy($id)
{
  $packings = Packing::find($id);
  $packings->delete();
  return redirect('trips')->with('success', 'Item Deleted from Packing List');
}
```

**models**

```
public function trip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Trip', 'trip_id');
}

public function packings() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Packing');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  //validate given Request
  $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required|string|max:225',
    'trip_id' => 'required|numeric' //we want it to be number
  ]);

  //create a new incompletete item with given title
  $packings = new Packing;
  $packings->title = $request->input('title');
  $packings->is_complete = false;
  $packings->trip_id = $request['trip_id'];
  $packings->save();

  return redirect('packingList')->with('success', 'Item added to Packing List');
}
```

Comment: I get the message "The trip id must be a number."

Comment: That's why the insertion was failing at DB level. DB expects trip_id to be a number, not string.

Now that we've added a validation check, we're catching it. I guess you're sending trip id as string `'17'` instead of `17`. 

Here's what you can do. Modify:
`$packings->trip_id = (int) $request['trip_id']; //cast to number`

Comment: hm i still seem to be getting same message "The trip id must be a number."

Comment: Remove the numeric validation:
`'trip_id' => 'required'

So validation passes, our casting  here `$packings->trip_id = (int) $request['trip_id'];` will convert to integer before saving.